# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backports'

Tags: python, android, github-actions, lzma, python-for-android

Basically I'm making an app using Pythons kivy and kivymd frame work.In my app I'm using instaloader module.Using Github Action (CI) I'm converting my app to apk.
After converting,when i try to open my apk it crashes immediately.

Here's my `Debug Log`

```
I/python ( 8065): Traceback (most recent call last): 
I/python ( 8065): File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 9, in <module> 
I/python ( 8065): File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/stalkgram/arm64-v8a/instaloader/__init__.py", line 16, in <module> 
I/python ( 8065): File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/stalkgram/arm64-v8a/instaloader/instaloader.py", line 24, in <module> 
I/python ( 8065): File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/stalkgram/arm64-v8a/instaloader/nodeiterator.py", line 7, in <module> 
I/python ( 8065): File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module 
I/python ( 8065): File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/lzma.py", line 27, in <module> 
I/python ( 8065): ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma' 
I/python ( 8065): Python for android ended.
```

Here's my `build.yml` (CI)

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get Date
        id: get-date
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=date::$(/bin/date -u "+%Y%m%d")"
        shell: bash

      - name: Cache Buildozer global directory
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer_global
          key: buildozer-global-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }}

      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: .buildozer
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ steps.get-date.outputs.date }}-${{ hashFiles('buildozer.spec') }}
      - name: Install AIDL
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install build-essential
          sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
          sudo apt-get install aidl    
          sudo apt-get install -y liblzma-dev
          pip3 install backports.lzma
          pip3 install backports.weakref       
          
      - name: Build with Buildozer        
        uses: ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action@v1
        id: buildozer
        with:
          command: buildozer android debug
          buildozer_version: master

      - name: Modify lzma.py
        run: |
          cd .buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib

          sudo apt-get install -y liblzma-dev
          pip3 install backports.lzma
          pip3 install backports.weakref
          cd /home/runner/work/Stalkgram/Stalkgram
          ls
          sudo cp lzma.py .buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib
          
      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: package
          path: ${{ steps.buildozer.outputs.filename }}
```

Here's my  `buildozer.spec` requirements.

`requirements = python3==3.9.10,hostpython3==3.9.10,kivy==2.1.0,pillow,kivymd==1.1.1,certifi,android,instaloader==4.10.1,plyer==2.1.0`

Then i solved this issue following this

```
 Before modification 
from _lzma import * 
from _lzma import _encode_filter_properties, _decode_filter_properties 

After modification 
try: 
 from _lzma import * 
 from _lzma import _encode_filter_properties, _decode_filter_properties 
except ImportError: 
 from backports.lzma import * 
 from backports.lzma import _encode_filter_properties, _decode_filter_properties
```

And it works.But now getting another error and that is

```
I/python  ( 7917):    File "/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/app/lzma.py", line 31, in <module>
I/python  ( 7917):  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backports'
I/python  ( 7917): Python for android ended.
```

Comment: Aren't you testing the final `.apk` file represented by `steps.buildozer.outputs.filename`? If yes, how does "Modify lzma.py" step affect it? The first 4 commands of "Modify lzma.py" look redundant as "Install AIDL" step is already doing it. However, in the absence of https://github.com/actions/setup-python, the default [preinstalled Python version](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#language-and-runtime) is used but you're using 3.9.10. Have you verified the version being used and that it's not an issue for your build?

Comment: And, https://github.com/ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action?tab=readme-ov-file supports multiple commands via its [`command`](https://github.com/ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action?tab=readme-ov-file#command) input parameter. Not sure if using it to install the required pip3 deps the right approach. You might want to look into it.

Comment: Under [caching](https://github.com/ArtemSBulgakov/buildozer-action?tab=readme-ov-file#caching), it's recommending against caching local `.buildozer` directory. Have you observed anything different if you skip it?

Comment: Try just adding `import backports` (without `try:`/`except:`) that should allow kivy to detect that it needs to bundle backports in your app.